# Oracle 11gR2: ORA-01102: cannot mount database in EXCLUSIVE mode

Tags: oracle, dbms

I am running Oracle 11gR2 on an AIX box.  I did a rename database and change DB ID using NID.  I can restart db in a nomount mode, but I can not mount it by the following error.

```
ORA-01102: cannot mount database in EXCLUSIVE mode
ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01507: database not mounted
```

I started DB by using a new pfile.  I notice that the NID utility did not change the old DB folder names in ASM.  So this rename database effort will not be perfect.

I have already removed some easy things when I Googled this error, such as removing the lk* files under $ORACLE_HOME/dbs.

Any suggestions for me to start the database after the renaming command of NID?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for JSapkato's response.  This made me thinking to find that elusive database instance that prevented me from mounting my database.

It turns out that I made a mistake and used the 1st DB's control file name in the 2nd DB's pfile.  I changed the control file names according to the "real" ones in ASM.  Now I do not get this "exclusive" mounting errors.

Note:  I was following the Oracle document on how to change DB name:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dbnewid.htm

Answer (score 6):

> #### ORA-01102 cannot mount database in EXCLUSIVE mode
>
> **Cause:** Some other instance has the database mounted exclusive or shared.
>   **Action:** Shut down the other instance or mount in a compatible mode.

Find whether you have any running Oracle process.

```
$ ps -ef | grep smon
```

Kill the process then try to start again.

Since I dont have the procedure which you have followed to perform DB rename and DBID change I can not say whether there is problem with your procedure.

I would recommend to follow Oracle Knowledge Document to perform such task. 
[How to Change the DBID and the DBNAME by using NID](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=1bugqxbufh_79&_afrLoop=3781678184126#REF)

Comment: I believe my mistake was that I used 2nd DB on the same server's control file name in pfile.  I hope that bymodifying the control file names in the pfile, I can open the DB.  Will post the results later.

Answer (score -1):

Run given command:

#### kill -9 `ps -e | grep ora_* | awk '{print $1} ###`

This will kill all processes associated with oracle, like smon, pmon, dbwriter processes.
Then start again with `. oraenv & sqlplus / as sysdba`